# Inspecting BitString Data type in elixir interactive shell doesn't show info

Tags: module, elixir, elixir-iex

Querying `i("my string")` returned data type of BitString

Running `h(BitString)` command in `iex` returns `Could not load module BitString, got: nofile`.

Compared to other data types that return module info on prompt, this particular module doesn't seem to serve any response. How do I view info regarding `BitString` in `iex`?

Queried `i('my string')` instead but this is of a `List` data type instead.

`h(List)` does return info on this module type.

I am interested in info pertaining to `BitString` data type

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IEx.Helpers.i/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#i/1) prints a result of applying [`IEx.Info.info/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Info.html#info/1) to the term. As per documentation,

> - "Data type": Name of the data type. **Usually** the name of the module defining the data type.

That said, `BitString` is just a name. If you are interested in the modules that are used to handle the type, you might read what `i/1` printed to the end.

```
iex||1 ▸ i("f")
Term
  "f"
Data type
  BitString
Byte size
  1
Description
  This is a string: a UTF-8 encoded binary. It's printed surrounded by
  "double quotes" because all UTF-8 encoded code points in it are printable.
Raw representation
  <<102>>
Reference modules
  String, :binary
Implemented protocols
  Collectable, IEx.Info, Inspect, List.Chars, String.Chars
```

and see *Reference modules:* `String`, `:binary`.

---

The confusion is most likely provoked by the fact that there is no explicit mapping `type` → `module`, because types in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) are not like types in OOP languages, the type is either defined by [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) and then it has *no defining module at all*, only modules providing helper functions to deal with it, or is a struct, then it’s defined in some particular module.